# What programming languages and what software would I need to use to make a Windows Program that uses Kinect data?

Tags: windows, kinect

I want to make a computer program on windows that uses data from my Kinect. What languages could I use and what software would help me in the process?

EDIT: Okay so I found the Kinect SDK from Windows. Anything other downloads that would help that I should know about?

Comment: For the `official` Microsoft Kinnect drivers, see http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/kinectsdk/download.aspx for the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to use the official SDK instead of the OpenNI drivers, your programming language choices are basically C# or C++. You can download Visual Studio C# or C++ Express versions for free [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express) to use as your IDE. To use the speech recognition, you'll need to download the following:

- [Microsoft Speech Platform - SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1b1604d3-4f66-4241-9a21-90a294a5c9a4&displaylang=en) (download the x86 version)
- [Microsoft Speech Platform - Server Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=bb0f72cb-b86b-46d1-bf06-665895a313c7) (download the x86 version)
- [Kinect for Windows Runtime Language Pack](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=220942)

Honestly, just check out the [Kinect SDK documentation](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/kinectsdk/guides.aspx). There's a ton of awesome information, including everything in this post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the MS SDK, but OpenKinect cross platform and language wrapper details can be found here: http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a Microsoft technology, It's highly probable that you will have to use .NET, i.e. C# and the likes.

The Kinect SDK can be found here : http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/kinectsdk/

Answer (score 0):

If you are just starting out with the Kinect, it is probably best suited that you use the [Microsoft Kinect SDK v2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44561). It is the fastest way to get off the ground with the Kinect. In the SDK, you will be programming in C# or C++. Please do note that this is only compatible with Windows.

If you hate C#/C++, are not using Windows, or have advanced knowledge of other languages instead, you can use [Open Connect](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started) and your favorite language (C++, C#, Python, JAVA, Javascript, or Lisp)